# XSLT Muenchian Grouping Ignore Specific Groups

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I have XML like this:

```
  <DocumentElement>
    <ManagerReport>
        <UserName>username</UserName>
        <ShortTerm>2</ShortTerm>
        <LongTerm>4</LongTerm>
        <SupervisorContact>ADMIN@COMPANY.COM</SupervisorContact>
        <DBName>SQLDB1</DBName>
      </ManagerReport>
... more ManagerReport nodes...
  </DocumentElement>
```

Which I am grouping (Muenchian grouping) based on DBName with the following key:

```
<xsl:key name="groups" match="ManagerReport" use="./DBName"/>
```

and the following templates:

```
<xsl:template match="/DocumentElement">
<HTML>
  <BODY>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="ManagerReport[generate-id() = generate-id(key('groups', ./DBName)[1])]"/>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

```
  <xsl:template match ="ManagerReport">
  <TEXT>
    The following employees have documents checked out in <xsl:value-of select="./DBName"/>:
  </TEXT>
  <BR></BR>
  <TABLE Border = "1">
    <TR>
      <TH>Username</TH>
      <TH>Short Term</TH>
      <TH>Medium Term</TH>
      <TH>Long Term</TH>
    </TR>
    <xsl:for-each select="key('groups',./DBName)">
      <xsl:if test="./SupervisorContact = $mgr">
      <TR>
        <TD>
          <xsl:value-of select ="./UserName"/>
        </TD>
        <TD>
          <xsl:call-template name ="ApplyTemplatesOrDefault">
            <xsl:with-param name="elem" select="./ShortTerm"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="default">0</xsl:with-param>
          </xsl:call-template>
        </TD>
        <TD>
          <xsl:call-template name ="ApplyTemplatesOrDefault">
            <xsl:with-param name="elem" select="./MedTerm"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="default">0</xsl:with-param>
          </xsl:call-template>
        </TD>
        <TD>
          <xsl:call-template name ="ApplyTemplatesOrDefault">
            <xsl:with-param name="elem" select="./LongTerm"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="default">0</xsl:with-param>
          </xsl:call-template>
        </TD>
      </TR>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </TABLE>
  <BR></BR>
  <BR></BR>
```

This result of this template is a table for each database containing the information in the appropriate manager report nodes. The `mgr` value is passed in as a parameter, in order to only print `ManagerReport` values that correspond to a particular supervisor.

This works great, except for the fact that if a there are no nodes that correspond to a particular `SupervisorContact` for a given `DBName`, an empty table (just the headers) is printed. I do not want to print these particular tables.

The only approach I can imagine is to add a predicate to the `match` on the `groups` key, which is strictly not allowed. How can I get rid of these "empty" tables?

Please note I am using, and must use XSL **1.0**.

Comment: Can't you just use `<xsl:apply-templates select="ManagerReport[generate-id() = generate-id(key('groups', ./DBName)[1]) and key('groups', DBName)[SupervisorContact = $mgr]"/>`?

Comment: @MartinHonnen That doesn't evaluate to a node set.

Comment: Please include entire XSLT in one code block and not broken up.

Comment: It looks like I didn't get the syntax right, should be `<xsl:apply-templates select="ManagerReport[generate-id() = generate-id(key('groups', ./DBName)[1]) and key('groups', DBName)[SupervisorContact = $mgr]]"/>`,

Comment: @MartinHonnen worked perfectly, thank you!

Comment: I have morphed the comment into an answer so that you can close the question as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you can put the condition on the `xsl:apply-templates` by replacing `<xsl:apply-templates select="ManagerReport[generate-id() = generate-id(key('groups', ./DBName)[1])]"/>` with `<xsl:apply-templates select="ManagerReport[generate-id() = generate-id(key('groups', ./DBName)[1]) and key('groups', DBName)[SupervisorContact = $mgr]]"/>`.